# Unable to connect secured websocket

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, websocket, socket.io

Using nodejs this client code isn't working:

```
var sock= require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;


var sock= new W3CWebSocket("wss://" + 'www.mysite.com'+ ':31333');

sock.onopen = function (evt)
    {
        console.log("it never reaches here");


//..................
}
```

Actually it was working when my nodejs server wasn't using SSL so this code used to work:

```
var sock= new W3CWebSocket("ws://" + 'www.mysite.com'+ ':31333');
```

The server code is looks like this:

```
var ws = require("./nodejs-websocket");
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    secure: true,
    key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/mysite.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/mysite.com.crt')
};

var server = ws.createServer(options, function (conn)
    {
        console.log("New connection")
        conn.on("text", function (str)
            {

               //some code here

            });
        conn.on("close", function (code, reason)
            {
                console.log("Connection closed")
            });

    }).listen(31333);
```

From browser I'm able to communicate to this server using Websockets. But not from the Linux commandline.
How to make it working from Linux commandline?

Answer (score 0):

I can not speak much to the library you are using.  But I had to have secure WebSockets as well for a recent . and used this library instead 
[socket.io-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis)
[socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)
They specifically allow you to use secure connections.  Below is a code example of how this works and the above links will lead to the documentation.

```
var redis = require('redis');

var client = redis.createClient(config.redisPort,config.redis,
  {auth_pass: config.reDISCACHEKEY, tls: {servername: config.redis}}); //creates a new client
var sclient=redis.createClient(config.redisPort,config.redis,
  {auth_pass: config.reDISCACHEKEY, tls: {servername: config.redis}}); //creates a new client

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

io.adapter(redis({pubClient:client,subClient:sclient}))

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  client.set(socket.handshake.query.userName, socket.id);

    //sets what happens when a socket disconnects
    //deletes socket information

   socket.on('disconnect', function(){
     let name=socket.handshake.query.userName;
     client.del(name, function(err, reply) {
     });
   });
   socket.on('message', function(msg, func){
     let name=socket.handshake.query.userName;
     let sockectObj=msg;
     io.emit('Message', sockectObj);
   });
 });
```

Let me know if more is needed